# file not recognized: File format not recognized

Tags: c, makefile

when i run a make file i get this error

"obj/viojournal.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status"

and the make file is as follows

how to fix this problem.
i am using gcc compiler on centos 5.4 linx 64bit machine.

```
all: libvioft.so fdump syncer

CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I../clogger -I../marshall -I../ddp  \
     -I../http -I../xml -I../nfsop  -I../include/common -I../restful \
     -I../include/oneGrid

CFLAGS = -g3 -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -DREPLICATION_ENABLED -DJOURNALING_ENABLED

#CFLAGS = -g3 -Wall -Wextra -fPIC

LDFLAGS = -Wl,-rpath=\$$ORIGIN -Wl,-rpath=\$$ORIGIN/../clogger \
    -Wl,-rpath=\$$ORIGIN/../marshall -Wl,-rpath=\$$ORIGIN/../ddp \
    -Wl,-rpath=\$$ORIGIN/../http  -Wl,-rpath=\$$ORIGIN/../xml \
    -Wl,-rpath=\$$ORIGIN/../restful

LIBS = -lpthread -lssl -lxml2 -lbz2 -L../clogger -lclogger \
    -L../marshall -lmarshall -L../ddp -lddp -L../nfsop -lnfsop

libsources = filefs.c viojournal.c recvReplicaUpdate.c syncer.c hostops.c filetable.c updateRemoteFT.c checkpoint.c 
#libsources = filefs.c viojournal.c hostops.c filetable.c checkpoint.c container.c locks.c

libobjects = $(libsources:%.c=obj/%.o)

fttestsources = fttest2.c
fttestobjects = $(fttestsources:%.c=obj/%.o)

syncersources = syncer.c
syncerobjects = $(syncersources:%.c=obj/%.o)

#dmpsources = viodump.c hostops.c
#dmpobjects = $(dmpsources:%.c=obj/%.o)

libvioft.so: $(libobjects)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared -o libvioft.so $(libobjects)

fdump: $(fttestobjects) libvioft.so
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o fdump $(fttestobjects)

syncer: $(syncerobjects) libvioft.so
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o syncer $(syncerobjects)

viodump: $(dmpobjects)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -lpthread -o viodump $(dmpobjects)

clean: 
    rm -rf fttest viodump atar syncer libvioft.so obj

install: 
    cp -f libvioft.so ../package/lib    
#   cp -f syncer ../package/bin

obj/%.d: %.c
    $(SHELL) -ec 'mkdir -p obj && $(CC) -MM $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -MT $(@:.d=.o) -MT $@ $< > $@'

obj/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

include $(libsources:%.c=obj/%.d)
include $(tstsources:%.c=obj/%.d)
include $(atrsources:%.c=obj/%.d)
#include $(dmpsources:%.c=obj/%.d)
```

Comment: Did you try `make clean` first?

Answer (score 12):

It seems like the object file is corrupted somehow. Try deleting it to force it to be rebuilt or as @devnull suggests, do a `make clean`.

Comment: thanks for u suggestion is there any problem with make file...??

Comment: @harish013 I don't speak `Makefile`, sorry. I use stuff like CMake to `make` my life easier `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

(I would put this suggestion as a comment, but I don't have enough, Reputation yet)

I ran into this error recently, and I have a couple of suggestions that might help.

In my case, the `makefile`(s) in question needed different `CFLAGS` depending on whether the installation was 64-bit or 32-bit. Here are some lines from the [`README`](https://github.com/chinshr/sctk/blob/master/README)

> `By default, the C/C++ software are compiled in 32 bits with the options (-Os) but can be compiled in 64 bits, -m64 is added to the CFLAGS variable in <certain makefiles in the project are listed>`

My suggestion is to first try adding `-m64` to your `CFLAGS`. If that doesn't work, delete the `-m64` and replace it with `-Os`.

That is, first try having the following line:

```
CFLAGS = -g3 -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -DREPLICATION_ENABLED -DJOURNALING_ENABLED -m64
```

Then, from the command line, run

```
make clean
```

Followed by whatever `make` commands you use for your install.

If that doesn't work, change the line in question to

```
CFLAGS = -g3 -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -DREPLICATION_ENABLED -DJOURNALING_ENABLED -Os
```

Then `make clean` and the other `make` stuff.

If some of the C objects are 64-bit and some are 32-bit (I don't know if such a situation actually exists), you might have to do something different.

This worked in my case, details of which you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50278663/6505499).

Please comment to let me know if it works for you.